# Cannot see Whatsapp photos in Lumia 520 gallery

Tags: whatsapp, photos

I cannot see Whatsapp photos in my gallery on my Lumia 520. But I can see them on my laptop.

How can I view them in the gallery?

Comment: You renamed the Whatsapp's folder with a file management app or something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
Connect your phone to ur pc via usb..

Go to sb card->picture-> select WhatsApp folder rename it to WhatsApp1 or WhatsApp2 as per ur wish..

Now open WhatsApp in ur phone download any picture from there now check your photos app WhatsApp folder is created and that picture you downloaded will show therr..

Now go to your earlier renamed folder copy all the contents of those folder to this new WhatsApp folder.